# Why catch exceptions when we can simply prevent them from happening in the first place

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I've always had trouble understanding the real purpose of catching exceptions in any programming language.

Generally, when you can catch an exception, you can also prevent the exception from ever occurring. Here's an example.

What's the point of doing this:

```
import os
import argparse

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, help="the filename")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    try:
        with open(args.filename) as fs:
            fs.write("test")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("that file was not found")
```

If I can do this:

```
import os
import argparse

if __name__=="__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, help="the filename")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if os.path.exists(args.filename):
        with open(args.filename) as fs:
            fs.write("test")
    else:
        print("that file was not found")
```

What is the added value of catching *anything* as an exception, when it is often more feasible to prevent the exception from ever happening in the first place?

Comment: The file not existing is not the only reason that the `open` might fail.  Maybe you have the proper permissions to list the file, but you don't have permission to read it.  This is generally the answer to your question.  There will often be potential unforseen consequences that you can't test for in advance.  This is very common on the web, for example, where servers can go down or be overloaded.

Comment: @CryptoFool Let's suppose that's the only thing that can go wrong here. As I have demonstrated it's often possible to prevent the error from taking place in the first place. I could also have added more conditionals in that if statement checking if I have permission to read the file, and so on and so forth.

Comment: The answer is that it's situational.  Sometimes it's better to proactively prevent an exception from being raised, other times it's better to separate your error handling from your main control flow.  If you get dogmatic about doing it one way or the other in every single situation you'll end up writing some really awkward code.

Comment: @Samwise if it's situational then how do I know which one is appropriate?

Comment: Experience, mostly.  If you're not sure, try writing it both ways, and see which is simpler.  When you do try to prevent exceptions proactively, pay attention to situations where you failed to anticipate a particular exception, and as you fix the bug by adding another `if/else`, ask yourself, "would this be easier with a single `try/except`?"  As long as you're always open to the possibility that there might be a better way of doing things, you'll naturally converge on the best approach.  If you get stuck on a particular approach and never reconsider it, you end up writing bad code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are so set on avoiding exceptions.  You asked "what's the added value".  The added value is that you'll catch things you can't anticipate.  Beyond that, it's a matter of style.  As others have said, either approach is worth trying.  I often do both...do what I can to preflight, but still have the catch there just in case.  Let me ask you the same question but flipped over..."What's the added value of avoiding the use of Exceptions?"

Comment: The added value of avoiding the use of exceptions is that you anticipate every that can go wrong and design against that. Also, I'm not "set" on avoiding exceptions. I'm rather looking for concrete examples of situations in which *only* try-catch blocks can solve a given problem. So far I have never come across such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are exceptional situations being thrown when an undesired, erroneous issue happened. It is true that in many cases it is unnecessary to use the exception pattern as you can check for the possibility to perform the operation before giving it a chance to err. But, sometimes that's not possible.

For instance, let's consider the example that you are running a database query. You cannot know whether that will succeed without actually running it. So, there are cases when you cannot prevent exceptions by doing validations.

Also, there are cases when there could be many exceptions upon many levels. Your code would become very difficult to read and work with if you validate everything. Consider the case when you have a method that receives an object and calls 100 other methods, passing the same object.

When do you validate whether that object was properly initialized? Do you validate it at the method that calls the other methods only? But then, later somebody else might call one of the 100 methods from another place without validating it. So, if we are to only validate, then we will end up writing the same validating code in 101 methods, instead of catching the exception at a single place, regardless of which method throws it.

You will also need to use third-party libraries. Are they perfect? Probably not quite and not all of them. How do you validate everything in the code written by someone else?

Summary:

- sometimes there is no way to know whether an operation succeeds before running it
- third-party libraries will come as they are, possibly with errors, you cannot apply validation for them, unless you get into their code and refactor the whole thing (you could as well write the whole library instead)
- doing validation-only may lead to code repetition, unreadable code, code difficult to maintain and very long refactoring when the duplicated validation needs to be changed
- you cannot think about all the possible errors, you need at least a layer that catches the problems you didn't foresee
- when you upgrade some versions, like Python version for example, it is quite possible that something will no longer work

Validating operations is often a good idea, but it cannot substitute exception handling. They are going hand-in-hand. You validate what makes sense to be validated and that's often a subjective decision, but, if still an exception occurs, you need to handle that properly